# Laravel 5 - Call to undefined method

Tags: php, laravel, model, laravel-5

I am trying to call a method within the model, in my view, but I am being presented with this error:

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::hasLogo()
>   (View: /Users/Documents/audit/resources/views/misc/logo.blade.php)

**Model: (Site)**

```
  public function hasLogo()
  {
    return File::exists(public_path($this->logo->url()));
  }
```

**Controller: (HomeController.php)**

```
  public function showLogo()
  {
    $sites = Site::where('user_id', Auth::id());
    return View::make('misc.logo')->with(['sites' => $sites]);
  }
```

**View: logo.blade.php**

```
@if ($sites->hasLogo())

<img src="<?= $sites->logo->url('medium') ?>" alt="<?= $sites->name ?>" 
          class="img-rounded col-md-12" style="padding-bottom: 20px;">

@endif
```

I am unsure why it cannot find this method within the `Site` model. Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not retrieving anything. This is what you have right now:

```
$sites = Site::where('user_id', Auth::id());
```

That merely preps the query. You haven't fetched anything until you call a method like `first()`, `get()`, etc. So, try this instead:

```
$sites = Site::where('user_id', Auth::id())->firstOrFail();
```

`firstOrFail()` will also fetch only one site. If you want to fetch all sites that meet the requirement, you will need to use `get()` and then loop through the sites.

```
$sites = Site::where('user_id', Auth::id())->get();
foreach ($sites as $site)
{
    if ($site->hasLogo())
    {
        // etc.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Complete your query here:

```
$sites = Site::where('user_id', Auth::id())->get();
```

Call `get()` or `first()` depending on your need.

and now you'll be able to call your custom method.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sites = Site::where('user_id', Auth::id());
```

Should be

```
$sites = Site::where('user_id', Auth::id())->get(); // ->get() the data

foreach($sites as $site) {
    if( $site->hasLogo() ) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

If you don't call `get()`, it'll still be a query builder object. If you call `hasLogo()` or `logo()` on `$sites`, it will fail because that's an [eloquent collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-collections), not a model.